# WPF and 3D how do you change a single position point in 3D space?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I have a VERY simple 3D space defined in WPF, which defines a 3D rectangle, I was hoping to be able to manipulate each one of the Point3D objects (in the "Positions") property on the MeshGeometry3D, but Im having trouble with it...

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Viewport3D Name="ViewPort" 
                Focusable="true" 
                ClipToBounds="true" 
                Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas, Mode=Default}" 
                Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=canvas, Mode=Default}">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
      <PerspectiveCamera Position="0,0,5"/>
     </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup>
                    <PointLight Color="White" Position="0,0,0">
                        <PointLight.Transform>
                            <Transform3DGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0" OffsetZ="0"/>
                                <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" ScaleZ="1"/>
                                <RotateTransform3D d:EulerAngles="0,0,0">
                                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0,1,0"/>
                                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                </RotateTransform3D>
                                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0" OffsetZ="2"/>
                            </Transform3DGroup>
                        </PointLight.Transform>
                    </PointLight>

                    <GeometryModel3D x:Name="model1" Material="{DynamicResource test1}">
                        <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                            <Transform3DGroup>
                                <RotateTransform3D>
                                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="1,0,0" Angle="5" />
                                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                </RotateTransform3D>
                                <RotateTransform3D>
                                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,1,0" Angle="-5" />
                                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                </RotateTransform3D>
                            </Transform3DGroup>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D
           Positions=" -0.5,  0.5, 0.0
                                            -0.5, -0.5, 0.0
                                             1.5, -0.5, 0.0
                                             1.5,  0.5, 0.0"
           TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0"
           TriangleIndices="0 1 2 2 3 0" />
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="canvas" s:Contacts.ContactDown="canvas_ContactDown"  Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=window, Mode=Default}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=window, Mode=Default}">
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

where test1 is just an image wrapped in a visual brush.

And here is my c#:

```
private void canvas_ContactDown(object sender, ContactEventArgs e)
    {
        //Point contactPosition = e.GetPosition(this);
        //var rayMeshResult = (RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult)VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(ViewPort, e.GetPosition(ViewPort));
        translatedX -= 0.25;
        translatedY -= 0.25;
        model1.Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(translatedX, translatedY, 0.0);
        //model1.Transform.Transform(new Point3D(translatedX, translatedY, 0.0));

        Console.WriteLine("Changed");
        //Apply Z index changes here...
        var geometry3D = model1.Geometry as MeshGeometry3D;
        Point3DCollection positions = geometry3D.Positions;

        foreach (var position in positions)
        {
            position.Offset(0,0,-15);
        }
    }
```

But nothing happens in the visual screen...

One thing I want to specifically mention is that I do not want to apply a transformation to the entire object, just one point at a time.

But if thats the only way then I guess Ill have to look into it

Thanks for any help you can give.

Mark

Comment: Would you post a more complete sample?  I'm wondering based on your XAML if "model1" isn't being frozen, but if that were the case I'd expect an exception to be thrown, rather than nothing happening.

Comment: Ive got the full code up now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it, it was because geometry3D.Positions returns a collection of Point3D objects, which are structs, so when you reference them, you are not changing the one that you think you are changing...

So a loop more like this does the trick:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
        {
            Point3D position = positions[i];
            position.Z += 5;
            positions[i] = position;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the issue in a better way.

```
TranslateTransform3D mytranslate = new TranslateTransform3D();
mytranslate.OffsetX = 0;
mytranslate.OffsetY = 0;
mytranslate.OffsetZ = 5;
model1.Transform = mytranslate;
```