# How to animate a Point in a MeshGeometry3D in WPF/XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d

Is it possible to animate points in a MeshGeometry3D? either in XAML or in C# code behind.

I can't seem to find a way to animate the X,Y,Z locations of points over time.
Any ideas?

This may help.. [WPF and 3D how do you change a single position point in 3D space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592136/wpf-and-3d-how-do-you-change-a-single-position-point-in-3d-space)

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I never found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not pretty

Xaml

```
<Viewport3D>
    <ModelVisual3D x:Name="VisualHost"/>
</Viewport3D>
```

CodeBehind

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    #region TargetZ Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetZProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TargetZ", typeof(double), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(TargetZ_Changed));

    private static void TargetZ_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var positions = ((MeshGeometry3D)((GeometryModel3D)d).Geometry).Positions;
        var point = positions[0];
        positions[0] = new Point3D(point.X, point.Y, point.Z + (double)e.NewValue);
    }

    public void SetTargetZ(GeometryModel3D d, double value)
    {
        d.SetValue(TargetZProperty, value);
    }
    public double GetTargetZ(GeometryModel3D d)
    {
        return (double)d.GetValue(TargetZProperty);
    }
    #endregion

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetNewZ(double newValue)
    {
        var animationTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        var model = (GeometryModel3D)VisualHost.Content;

        var zAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(newValue, animationTime) { FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd };
        model.BeginAnimation(TargetZProperty, zAnimation);
    }
}
```